# Simplify complex expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How can I simplify this expression? I tried the functions simplify and FullSimplify. Also the expand function didn't help me. I would like to know about solving such problems in more detail

```
((x^9 - x^6*y^3)^(1/3) - y^2*(8*x^6/y^3 - 8*x^3)^(1/3) + x*y*(y^3 - y^6/x^3)^(1/3))*(x + y)/(((x^8)^(1/3)*(x^2 - 2*y^2) + (x^2*y^12)^(1/3))*(1 + y/x + (y/x)^2)^(1/3))
```

Comment: `(x^3 - y^3)^(1/3)/((x + y) (x^2 + x y + y^2)^(1/3))` but it’s not until the end

Comment: What do you expect to get? Note that `(-1.)^(1/3) (-8.)^(1/3)` is not equal to `(8.)^(1/3)` (that is, $a^{1/3}b^{1/3}$ is not equivalent to $(ab)^{1/3}$).

Comment: Try `Simplify[expr, 0 < y && 0 < x]` and consider whether the assumption `0 < y  && 0 < x` is valid in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to simplify an expression like this is to add all the relevant assumptions to `FullSimplify`. For instance, if we use your expression, and assume that both `x` and `y` are positive, then you get a dramatically simplified result:

```
expr = ((x^9 - x^6*y^3)^(1/3) - y^2*(8*x^6/y^3 - 8*x^3)^(1/3) + 
     x*y*(y^3 - y^6/x^3)^(1/3))*(x + 
      y)/(((x^8)^(1/3)*(x^2 - 2*y^2) + (x^2*y^12)^(1/3))*(1 + 
         y/x + (y/x)^2)^(1/3));

FullSimplify[expr, {Positive[x], Positive[y]}]
(* (x - y)^(1/3)/(x + y) *)
```

Oftentimes, if you are experimenting with other functions to help in your quest to find a simpler form for an expression, you can check the language which assumptions they make about the expression and use those with `FullSimplify`. For example, the documentation for [`PowerExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand.html) says the following:

> The transformations made by PowerExpand are correct in general only if $c$ is an integer or $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers.

Obviously it would be very silly to assume that 1/3 is an integer, but it may be reasonable to assume that `x` and `y` are positive.

Comment: And how did you understand that these conditions are necessary, and not the actions described above?

Comment: Educated guessing. But if you look at the documentation for the functions above you'll see that they make implicit assumptions about the expressions that they're transforming.

Comment: And how can I find out these assumptions?

Comment: @ИскандарА See my first comment and consider that *Mathematica* treats variables as complex.  Some of the laws of exponents, such as $(ab)^p = a^pb^p$, apply only when the bases are positive real numbers.

Comment: You want to say that sometimes algebraic transformations can occur only under the condition that all numbers are positive?

Comment: @ИскандарА Yes, that's right, [some laws fail for nonpositive bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Failure_of_power_and_logarithm_identities).